# Find the sum $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} {1\over n^2}$ elementary!

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} {1\over n^2}$$ elementary! I know the result is $\pi^2/6$, but I wonder if there is an elementary approach i.e. with a high school knowledge to this sum.

Comment: Elementary? Fine: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\zeta(2)=\frac\pi6$$ Elementary is in the eyes of the beholder...elementary, Watson! And I doubt there are many high school in the globe that teach, as usual curriculum, the needed stuff to understand even the most elementary proofs of this fact.

Comment: @ DonAntonio Ok, but it is not $\pi^2/6$? So the answer is negative?

Comment: Your first try was $6/\pi$, remember?

Comment: There is an elementary way, since it was thesingle  problem for the French ‘baccalauréat’ (high school final exam)   some  30 years ago. Elementary, but long,since highschool student do not know much mathematics. They were allotted 4 hours for this exam problem.

Comment: Can Euler's approach be considered elementary? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem

Comment: Of course it is $\;\pi^2/6\;$ , @JohnWatson ...and I wouldn't dare to say there is no "elementary" proof in some sense. It is just that I know none

Comment: I am amazed that many high-rep users here did not see one of the most famous topics on MSE! Merry Xmas to you all, by the way.

Comment: Define "elementary", first. Curriculums of high schools vary.

Comment: Robert solution (on page 2) could be the most ''elementary'' approach. I'll have to think about it though.

Comment: The Wikipedi article [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)  tells how the problem was open for almost 100 years before Euler solved it. It Newton and Leibniz and other mathematicians could not solve it, what hope for an elementary solution?